# Число существительных рядом с числительным

Tags: числительные, единственное-множественное-число

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно:

Характеристики этого 121 случая представлены в Приложении ....
Характеристики этих 121 случаев представлены в Приложении ....
Характеристики этого 121 случаев представлены в Приложении ....

Контекст:
В процессе поиска в Глобальной базе данных по безопасности препарата обнаружено 158 случаев с зарегистрированными явлениями, относящимися к термину «инфекции, раздражения и воспаления век, ресниц и слезных путей». В 121 из этих случаев зарегистрированы термины халязион, блефарит, мейбомианит. Демографические данные и характеристики этого 121 случая представлены в Приложении 1.

Comment: Я бы советовал задать отдельный вопрос о том, как отредактировать весь текст.
Вот примеры того, что вызывает сомнение:

1. Выражение "в  базе данных обнаружены случаи" 
2. Словосочетание "случаи с зарегистрированными явлениями"
3. Выражение "явления, относящиеся к термину"
4. Является ли одним термином «инфекции, раздражения и воспаления век, ресниц и слезных путей»?
5. Словосочетание "зарегистрированы термины".
6. Следует ли писать термины в кавычках?

Comment: Контекст вообще не надо редактировать, он приведен для того, чтобы правильно понять заданный вопрос, который в этом случае отодвигается на второй план. Здесь важно было понять, как поступить с числительным, оканчивающимся на единицу, а не править весь текст. В вопросе было два интересных момента: местоимение перед числовым оборотом и необходимость в указании единицы измерения. Хотелось бы увидеть, как эти проблемы решаются.

Comment: @Jasmin "Контекст вообще не надо редактировать". == В рамках данного вопроса не надо его редактировать, поэтому я посоветовал задать отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Вы дали правильный совет. Также можно было как-то визуально отделить ответ на вопрос от редактирования контекста, пусть это будет дополнением к ответу, но только не сам ответ.  К примеру, при редактировании было использовано неполное предложение с падежной формой "в 121 из них". Это хороший вариант, но  он не универсальный.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение следует изменить, так как местоимение ***этих*** согласуется с существительным ***случаев*** во мн. числе , а числительное ***один*** требует согласования с существительным в ед. числе:

**Характеристики этих случаев (в количестве 121 факта) представлены в Приложении.**

Другой вариант: **Характеристика 121 случая по этой тематике...**

В любом случае нужен контекст, чтобы выбрать подходящую запись.

Comment: Факты ни к селу ни к городу, неужели не чувствуете? Может, это вовсе и не факты. В количестве 121 – скромненько и со вкусом.

Comment: Цифровая запись без существительного как-то странно смотрится, повторять его тоже некорректно, я посмотрела возможные синонимы и остановилась на слове "факты". Обычная запись выглядит так: были куплены ножницы в количестве 23 штук.

Comment: В данном случае не могу не поддержать нашего непримиримого борца @Niemand. Слово *факты* здесь неуместно.

Comment: А что уместно? Характеристики этих случаев в количестве 121  представлены в Приложении.  А читать это как, в И.п.? Посмотрите записи в Сети, все стараются указать единицу измерения, например: Информация о торгах: Мебель в количестве 5 ед. ... Источник питания в количестве 18 ед. Есть еще экземпляры, обязательно что-то есть.

Comment: @М_Г  И по поводу неуместности.  В этом слове присутствует определенная коннотация, что можно уточнить по словарю НЕУМЕСТНЫЙ,  Сказанный, сделанный и т.п. не вовремя, некстати; не соответствующий обстановке. Н. наряд. Н. разговор. Смех в церкви неуместен. Его присутствие было неуместным.  Вы уверены, что хотели сказать именно это?

Comment: В Вашем варианте нельзя однозначно понять смысл предложения. Я прочитал его так, что "характеристики каких-то случаев представлены в виде 121 факта".

Comment: @Jasmin, Спасибо за замечание. Я хотел сказать "не подходит по смыслу". А про неуместное употребление слов пишут, что это "потребление слов в несвойственном им значении". Строго говоря, это не одно и то же.  Признаю свою ошибку. Но здесь нет оттенка этической оценки.

Comment: А мне почему-то кажется, что у этого слова откровенная негативная коннотация. Я бы лучше сказала так: неправильное употребление слова, это слово сюда не подходит.  И в словаре значение "неправильный"  для  "неуместный" не указано, особенно в примерах.

Answer (score 1):

Ни один из предложенных в вопросе вариантов не подходит для публикации. Оказывается, не так-то просто найти "некорявое" решение. Предлагаю объединить два последних предложения в одно, тогда будет ясно, что "эти случаи" относится к 121 случаю:

...обнаружено 158 случаев... **<Некие явления> зарегистрированы в 121 из них;  характеристики этих случаев, а также демографические данные по ним представлены в Приложении 1.**

Answer (score 0):

Ваше предложение необходимо изменить. Понятно, что ранее в контексте упомянуты "эти" случаи, поэтому я бы предложил количество случаев указать ранее, а это предложение сформулировать так:
**Характеристики [всех] этих случаев представлены в Приложении...**

Если хотите получить более точный ответ, дайте, пожалуйста, 2-3 предыдущих предложения для понимания контекста (воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом).

**Дополнение** после уточнения вопроса.

Предлагаю следующий вариант правки.

> В процессе поиска в Глобальной базе данных по безопасности препарата
>   обнаружено 158 случаев с зарегистрированными явлениями, относящимися к
>   термину «инфекции, раздражения и воспаления век, ресниц и слезных
>   путей». Термины халязион, блефарит и мейбомианит зарегистрированы в 121
>   из них. Характеристики таких случаев, а также демографические данные по
>   ним представлены в Приложении 1.

Комментарии.
1. Смущает "демографические данные случаев". Я бы предложил не использовать такое выражение, если Вы не уверены, что оно употребляется в этом контексте в подобной специальной литературе.
2. Я сместил "121" в конец второго предложения, чтобы "случаи", упомянутые в третьем предложении понимались однозначно (с той же целью я использую слово "таких" вместо "этих").

Comment: спасибо за помощь!